# How to remove New line character from batch variable

Tags: batch-file, newline

Good Day All!
I have a batch script, and when I echo a variable like this

```
echo %variable1%
```

I get out put like this

```
TestLine1
TestLine2
TestLine3
TestLine4
```

My goal would be to modify this variable to remove all the newline characters so the output would look more like

```
TestLine1TestLine2TestLine3TestLine4
```

Is there a simple way to do this without creating files?
Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: It's not the easiest thing in the world to get newlines into an environment variable. Are you sure that your output is from echo`ing just one variable once, not from executing `echo`s in a loop?

Comment: Use this: `set /p ".=%variable1%"<nul`

Comment: @Squashman can you explain what your code does, and demonstrate it in a working example?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the command tr:

```
cleanedVariable1=$(echo $variable1 | tr -d '\n' )
echo $cleanedVariable1
```

The command tr removes or translates characters. The option -d removes the given characters. In this case, we are removing all new lines from our variable and assign it to a new variable.

Comment: That's powershell, not batch, and that's a gnu tool, not a native windows tool. That's why the question was downvoted.